# Unable to install wine32 due to broken packages

Tags: apt, wine

I'm attempting to install wine32 on **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS** (gnome 3.36.1 if it matters) with:
`sudo apt install wine32`

But receive the message:
`wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 5.0-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed`

Going down the chain of dependencies:

```
 libwine:i386 : Depends: libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libfaudio0:i386 (>= 19.06.07) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libopenal1:i386 (>= 1.14) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libpulse0:i386 (>= 0.99.1) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libudev1:i386 (>= 183) but it is not going to be installed
                Depends: libxml2:i386 (>= 2.9.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libcups2:i386 (>= 1.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libdbus-1-3:i386 (>= 1.9.14) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libsane:i386 (>= 1.0.24) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libtiff5:i386 (>= 4.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libxslt1.1:i386 (>= 1.1.25) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
```

And picking one at random and following it's dependencies all the way down to:

```
sudo apt install libgoa-1.0-common:i386 -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgoa-1.0-common' instead of 'libgoa-1.0-common:i386'
libgoa-1.0-common is already the newest version (3.36.0-1ubuntu1).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

What I've tried,

- running `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends winehq-stable` (after adding the WineHQ repo to sources), running apt update and trying again
- running `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` running apt update and trying again
- running `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, `sudo apt install -f`, `sudo apt install autoremove`
- accidentally uninstalling gnome...
- trying aptitude:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  glib-networking:i386{ab} glib-networking-services:i386{ab} gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386{a} gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386{a} gstreamer1.0-x:i386{a} i965-va-driver:i386{a} intel-media-va-driver:i386{a} libaa1:i386{a} libaom0:i386{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libasound2:i386{ab} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libavc1394-0:i386{a} libavcodec58:i386{a} libavutil56:i386{a} libbrotli1:i386{a} libcaca0:i386{a} libcairo-gobject2:i386{a} 
  libcairo2:i386{a} libcap2:i386{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcdparanoia0:i386{a} libcodec2-0.9:i386{a} libcups2:i386{ab} libcurl3-gnutls:i386{a} libdatrie1:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdv4:i386{a} libexif12:i386{ab} libfaudio0:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libfontconfig1:i386{a} 
  libfreetype6:i386{a} libfribidi0:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgdbm-compat4:i386{a} libgdbm6:i386{a} libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386{a} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} libgnutls30:i386{a} libgomp1:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port12:i386{a} 
  libgraphite2-3:i386{a} libgsm1:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:i386{a} libgstreamer1.0-0:i386{a} libgudev-1.0-0:i386{a} libharfbuzz0b:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhogweed5:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} libicu66:i386{a} libiec61883-0:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libigdgmm11:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} libjpeg8:i386{a} 
  libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{ab} libltdl7:i386{a} liblzma5:i386{ab} libmp3lame0:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libmysqlclient21:i386{a} libnettle7:i386{a} 
  libnghttp2-14:i386{a} libnuma1:i386{a} libodbc1:i386{a} libogg0:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libopenjp2-7:i386{a} libopus0:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpango-1.0-0:i386{a} libpangocairo-1.0-0:i386{a} libpangoft2-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libpcap0.8:i386{a} libpci3:i386{a} libperl5.30:i386{a} libpixman-1-0:i386{a} libpng16-16:i386{a} libproxy1v5:i386{a} libpsl5:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{ab} libraw1394-11:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} librsvg2-2:i386{a} librsvg2-common:i386{a} librtmp1:i386{a} 
  libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libsdl2-2.0-0:i386{a} libshine3:i386{a} libshout3:i386{a} libslang2:i386{a} libsnappy1v5:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libsndio7.0:i386{a} libsnmp35:i386{a} 
  libsoup2.4-1:i386{a} libsoxr0:i386{a} libspeex1:i386{a} libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssh-4:i386{a} libssl1.1:i386{a} libstb0:i386{a} libswresample3:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{ab} libtag1v5:i386{a} libtag1v5-vanilla:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libthai0:i386{a} libtheora0:i386{a} 
  libtiff5:i386{a} libtwolame0:i386{a} libudev1:i386{ab} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libva-drm2:i386{a} libva-x11-2:i386{a} libva2:i386{a} libvdpau1:i386{a} libvisual-0.4-0:i386{a} libvkd3d1:i386{a} libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} 
  libvpx6:i386{a} libwavpack1:i386{a} libwayland-cursor0:i386{a} libwayland-egl1:i386{a} libwebp6:i386{a} libwebpmux3:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwine:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx264-155:i386{a} libx265-179:i386{a} libxcb-render0:i386{a} libxcb-shm0:i386{a} 
  libxcb-xfixes0:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxkbcommon0:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} libxrender1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxss1:i386{a} libxv1:i386{a} libxvidcore4:i386{a} 
  libzvbi0:i386{a} mesa-va-drivers:i386{a} mesa-vdpau-drivers:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} va-driver-all:i386{a} vdpau-driver-all:i386{a} wine32:i386 
0 packages upgraded, 185 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 41.7 MB/97.0 MB of archives. After unpacking 548 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 glib-networking-services : Conflicts: glib-networking-services:i386 but 2.64.1-1 is to be installed
 glib-networking-services:i386 : Conflicts: glib-networking-services but 2.64.2-1build1 is installed
 libcups2 : Breaks: libcups2:i386 (!= 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1) but 2.3.1-9ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libcups2:i386 : Breaks: libcups2 (!= 2.3.1-9ubuntu1) but 2.3.1-9ubuntu1.1 is installed
 libldap-2.4-2 : Breaks: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (!= 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.2) but 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1 is to be installed
 libldap-2.4-2:i386 : Breaks: libldap-2.4-2 (!= 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1) but 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.2 is installed
 libsystemd0 : Breaks: libsystemd0:i386 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libsystemd0:i386 : Breaks: libsystemd0 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 is installed
 glib-networking : Breaks: glib-networking:i386 (!= 2.64.2-1build1) but 2.64.1-1 is to be installed
 glib-networking:i386 : Breaks: glib-networking (!= 2.64.1-1) but 2.64.2-1build1 is installed
 libasound2-data : Breaks: libasound2:i386 (< 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2) but 1.2.2-2.1 is to be installed
 libudev1 : Breaks: libudev1:i386 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3.2) but 245.4-4ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libudev1:i386 : Breaks: libudev1 (!= 245.4-4ubuntu3) but 245.4-4ubuntu3.2 is installed
 libexif12 : Breaks: libexif12:i386 (!= 0.6.21-6ubuntu0.1) but 0.6.21-6 is to be installed
 libexif12:i386 : Breaks: libexif12 (!= 0.6.21-6) but 0.6.21-6ubuntu0.1 is installed
 libpulse0 : Breaks: libpulse0:i386 (!= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3 is to be installed
 libpulse0:i386 : Breaks: libpulse0 (!= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.6 is installed
 libasound2 : Breaks: libasound2:i386 (!= 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2) but 1.2.2-2.1 is to be installed
 libasound2:i386 : Breaks: libasound2 (!= 1.2.2-2.1) but 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2 is installed
 liblzma5 : Breaks: liblzma5:i386 (!= 5.2.4-1ubuntu1) but 5.2.4-1 is to be installed
 liblzma5:i386 : Breaks: liblzma5 (!= 5.2.4-1) but 5.2.4-1ubuntu1 is installed
open: 26; closed: 1549; defer: 6; conflict: 14                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           oThe following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version:   
1)      glib-networking:i386 [Not Installed]                  
2)      glib-networking-services:i386 [Not Installed]         
3)      gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386 [Not Installed]        
4)      libasound2:i386 [Not Installed]                       
5)      libasound2-plugins:i386 [Not Installed]               
6)      libavahi-client3:i386 [Not Installed]                 
7)      libavcodec58:i386 [Not Installed]                     
8)      libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                         
9)      libcurl3-gnutls:i386 [Not Installed]                  
10)     libdbus-1-3:i386 [Not Installed]                      
11)     libexif12:i386 [Not Installed]                        
12)     libfaudio0:i386 [Not Installed]                       
13)     libgd3:i386 [Not Installed]                           
14)     libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]               
15)     libgphoto2-6:i386 [Not Installed]                     
16)     libgphoto2-port12:i386 [Not Installed]                
17)     libgudev-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                   
18)     libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                    
19)     liblzma5:i386 [Not Installed]                         
20)     libopenal1:i386 [Not Installed]                       
21)     libpci3:i386 [Not Installed]                          
22)     libpulse0:i386 [Not Installed]                        
23)     librsvg2-2:i386 [Not Installed]                       
24)     librsvg2-common:i386 [Not Installed]                  
25)     libsane:i386 [Not Installed]                          
26)     libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                    
27)     libsndio7.0:i386 [Not Installed]                      
28)     libsnmp35:i386 [Not Installed]                        
29)     libsoup2.4-1:i386 [Not Installed]                     
30)     libsystemd0:i386 [Not Installed]                      
31)     libtiff5:i386 [Not Installed]                         
32)     libudev1:i386 [Not Installed]                         
33)     libusb-1.0-0:i386 [Not Installed]                     
34)     libwine:i386 [Not Installed]                          
35)     libxml2:i386 [Not Installed]                          
36)     libxslt1.1:i386 [Not Installed]                       
37)     wine32:i386 [Not Installed]                           

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:            
38)     libopenal1:i386 recommends libasound2:i386 (>= 1.0.16)
39)     libwine:i386 recommends libsdl2-2.0-0:i386 (>= 2.0.10)
40)     libwine:i386 recommends gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:i386
```

Aptitude mentions conflicts but not sure if they are the issue. And if they are, why I have them and how to fix them.

Comment: Done. Sorry, totally forgot probably the most important detail...

Comment: Can you mention your responses in the `aptitude` command. Which ones did you accept and which ones did you deny - [Y/n].

Comment: It gave me a Y/n/q option for the output in the question and I chose Yes. I also did try hitting no which gave me a different list of packages. Hitting yes to that broke a lot of things but did not help. Can add the output after hitting no if you think relevant, it was just getting long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the conflicting package:

> ```
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>  glib-networking-services : Conflicts: glib-networking-services:i386 but 2.64.1-1 is to be installed
>  glib-networking-services:i386 : Conflicts: glib-networking-services but 2.64.2-1build1 is installed
> ```

It seems you have a repository that has been active then disabled.

Details: a version conflict for a package between architectures i386 and amd64(default). Because one of them is old and was installed from repository that not accessible or has been disabled.

Check which repository using:

```
apt-cache policy glib-networking-services glib-networking-services:i386
```

and `software-properties-gtk` ("Software Sources")

Comment: Thanks, yes, this was more or less the issue. I did a clean install of Ubuntu 20 and checked the package lists, which led me to check the sources list. I could see many differences, possibly I had messed it up while upgrading from Ubuntu 19 to 20. Adding sources that were in the clean install to my older upgraded install allowed me update many packages and subsequently was able to install the wine32 packge.

Comment: @LewisMarhin Great to hear that helped you. Just one more thing, APT/Aptitude hides default/native architecture, and that what confuse users. so `glib-networking-services` is actually more specific to call it `glib-networking-services:amd64`.  `:i386` are totally different packages than `:amd64` and they have separate repository index too. But generally hard related, like installed ones should be with same package version.

Answer (score 2):

I have similar problem but the problem because of `libudev1:i386` in repo that listed in `sources.list` file only reach version `237-3ubuntu10.42`, meanwhile, my libudev (arch amd64), has updated by automatic update to 237-3ubuntu10.43.

in your case:
glib-networking-services : Conflicts: glib-networking-services:i386 but 2.64.1-1
glib-networking-services:i386: Conflicts: glib-networking-services but 2.64.2-1build1

you see, the `amd64 arch version` different with the `amd32 arch version`, which the one is `2.64.1-1` version and the other is `2.64.2-1build1` version.

maybe it happens accidentially when we call `sudo apt upgrade`.

so try this:

```
sudo apt show glib-networking-services -a
```

and

```
sudo apt show glib-networking-services:i386 -a
```

watch the exists version, if you have both version in two package (watch the result in `apt show` step above)

show something like this:

```
glib-networking-services:i386 (2.64.2-1build1)
etc...
etc...

glib-networking-services:i386 (2.64.1-1)
etc...
etc...
```

and

```
glib-networking-services (2.64.2-1build1)
etc...
etc...
glib-networking-services (2.64.1-1)
etc...
etc...
```

so you lucky,when glib-networking-services (both arch), have 2.64.2-1build1 and have 2.64.1-1 just watch which version that already installed, e.g the `glib-networking-services` is already installed with version `2.64.2-1build1`, so if you have the version `2.64.2-1build1` for `glib-networking-services:i386` in your packages source.list, but in process to install `glib-networking-services:i386` automaticly always pick version `2.64.1-1`, so make the conflict, just type:

`sudo apt install glib-networking-services:i386=2.64.2-1build1`

to make sure installed the correct version.

but in my case, like I said before, the amd32 (:i386) version is not exists the newer version so the 64 arch package and the 32 arch package different version and make caused conflict / broken packages error. and impossible you can install the update version for the arch32 packages with this condition, where not exists in our `sources.list`

so what I'm doing to solve is, I search libudev1:i386 version 237-3ubuntu10.43 (search the .deb file) in google, lucky I found it in [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd). so I download the deb file.

after that install it with `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`

first attempt in installation process with `dpkg -i` will error but will show the cause of error. in my case happens because in the doc of libudev that record the version that exists in sources.lits not exists the version of 237-3ubuntu10.43.

the file that records it in `changelog.Debian.gz` in folder `/usr/share/doc/libudev1` (will show in error when run `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`).

so i rename that file with changelog.Debian.gz12, then do sudo `dpkg -i filename.deb` once again. now it success. after that you can install wine.

in my case the `libudev1:i386`, in your case..., `glib-networking-services:i386`, but i think the step is similar.

Comment: The goal of our Q&A model is to have a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu [*without chit-chat or distraction*](https://askubuntu.com/tour).  I'm not sure if or where your solution is buried under all of the narrative, but if it's there, it's very hard to find.  The answer/solution should be clearly stated.  Anything that doesn't help to answer is "distraction".  Can you please make an edit keeping this in mind?  If you have unsolved problems, please don't ask about them in your answer, instead you can ask a new question if needed.  You can link to this one for context.

Comment: I already solve with do the step that I explained above, and thanks for the "minus point" from you..., the problem is similar and anyone have different composition of dependencies. and the problem is not caused by the wine, it's because of the dependencies conflict. so it's a GENERAL problem about handle dependencies conflict. why the wine dependencies conflict with some dependencies in our system, it's base on what dependencies we install... so anybody that have problem with dependencies conflict (that caused broken package) can follow my step handle it. do you understood smart guys...?

Comment: and once again, no one explain the step that I explained above... you can try search anywhere...the key is...The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 glib-networking-services : Conflicts: glib-networking-services:i386 but 2.64.1-1 is to be installed
 glib-networking-services:i386 : Conflicts: glib-networking-services but 2.64.2-1build1 is installed... it's happen on me a dependencies conflict with another dependencies, the different just the dependencies... the different happen, big possibility caused by different configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Please try: `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Comment: Unfortunately the output is ```0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was related to these libraries:
• libgd3:i386
• libgd3

And the solution that helped me was to competely remove the repository that served different PHP versions:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge -y ppa:ondrej/php
```

After that, I was able to install wine amd64 and i386 packages from winehq.

Comment: this was also my problem package, but I resolved it using @Wahyu Bram's answer as I had some Frankendebian problem