# cannot install winehq-stable due to broken packages on 20.04 upgraded from 18.04

Tags: apt, upgrade, wine, downgrade, glibc

I found this article
[Unable to install wine32 due to broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1275983/unable-to-install-wine32-due-to-broken-packages)
but this is not quite the end of the story for me.

After digging down the dependency trees it seems that the underlying cause were older gcc-11 installation on the predecessor 18.04 holding essentials libraries.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgcc-s1 : Breaks: libgcc-s1:i386 (!= 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) but 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 is to be installed
 libgcc-s1:i386 : Breaks: libgcc-s1 (!= 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04) but 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1 is to be installed
```

So how on earth am i going to replace the libgcc with the right version?
Trying to remove the libgcc-s1 package is not an option as everything depends on it.

Answer (score 3):

Eventually I made some progress by **downgrading** some libs with the correct ubuntu-20.04 versions

```
apt install libgcc-s1=10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
apt install libstdc++6=10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
```

However, this was only a fraction on the path to get the wine installation working as I could see by further examination of the dependency conflicts of  *winehq-stable*.
Based on this my next step was a brute force approach which would **remove all 18.04 versions**:

```
apt remove $(dpkg -l | grep  \~18.04 | grep ii | awk '{ print $2}')
```

However, this also removed half the system **including the nvidia-driver**!
I had to reinstall the video and the desktop next before any reboot (and some lost AV software):

```
apt install nvidia-driver-470
apt install ubuntustudio-desktop
apt install clementine mixxx vlc
```

and finally it worked:
`apt install winehq-stable`

**What a bloody mission!**

this only happened because i really needed *wine* to run my tax software and I had a deadline ;)